# Can I create a function that reports a list of outputs in Python?

Tags: python

I am trying to get a list of outputs from functions.
For example, let's say I define a function called 'compute' as below

```
def compute(a, b):
    add = a + b
    sub = a - b
    return add, sub
```

What I want to do next is to create a new function that takes this 'compute' function as an argument and returns a list of outputs of the function, add and sub, as strings.

That is, if I name the function "output_list", I want the function `output_list(compute)` to return `['add', 'sub']`.

It seems it is supposed to be simple, but I have trouble writing it.
What should the code look like?

Comment: Return `['add', 'sub']`? What does that mean?

Comment: The outputs of `compute()` are two values, most likely numbers.  The fact that these values came from local variables named `add` and `sub` is an internal detail, not visible outside of the function.  So there is no reasonable function you could define that would produce `['add', 'sub']` here.

Comment: like ```[str(i) for i in compute(5,6)]``` ? you can write this into a function...

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. The names of the local variables inside `compute` are not known outside of `compute`. In fact, the local variables very likely do not even exist at runtime at all.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it might defeat the purpose but if you are the one who defines `compute` function, maybe you could do something like this:

```
from varname import nameof
def compute(a, b):
    add = a + b
    sub = a - b
    compute.output_list = [ nameof(add), nameof(sub) ]
    return add, sub

>>> compute.output_list
['add', 'sub']
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit confusing, how do you want to put a called function "**CONTAINS PARAMETERS**" as a Parameter for a other function without mentioning the Parameters' values?? its a bit confusing... Now, do you want the **Output** to be a list of the variables as string or you want to list the variables' results in a list???

I will consider the best scenario that you want to list the results of variables as a list of values for another function..

**Code Syntax**

```
def compute(a, b):
    add = a + b
    sub = a - b
    return [add, sub]


def another_function(lista= compute(3, 4)):
    return lista

print(another_function())
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[7, -1]

[Program finished]
```

Comment: I was not clear enough with my question. Apologies. Since I need to use the list of outputs "as a string" later in my code I wanted to define a function that reports a list of outputs so that I can collect them as a list of strings.

Comment: What kind of list of strings do you want, mate?? Still confusing!! Your first function is taking 2 integers parameters? Do you want the output of these integer converted to string? Example, the output in my post was [7, -1]. Do you want it displays like that ['7', '-1']??